# Метод получения общей стоимости всех товаров

Tags: javascript, функции, методы

Создать объект с розничной ценой и количеством продуктов. Этот объект также получает метод для получения общей стоимости всех товаров (цена * кол-во продуктов). У меня такой код, это верно, или нет?

```js
const obj = {
 price: 0,
 quantity: 0
 getPrice: getPrice
}

function getPrice() return{
 this.price * this.quantity
}
```

Comment: Нет, это неверно. Нажмите кнопку "Выполнить код", чтобы в этом убедиться.

Answer (score 2):

```js
const obj = {
  price: 2,
  quantity: 3.2,
  getPrice: getPrice
};

function getPrice() {
  return this.price * this.quantity;
}

console.log(obj.getPrice());
```